# Unable to call a block from template file

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

I have a custom module and created a block handle in my configuration file as below

```
    <blocks>
        <onestepcheckout>
            <class>Ucs_OneStepCheckout_Block</class>
        </onestepcheckout>
        .
        .
        .
    </blocks>
```

Then created a block file inside app/code/local/ucs/OneStepCheckout as below

```
<?php
class Ucs_OneStepCheckout_Block_Review extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getReviewTemplate()
    {
        return 'Success';
    }

}
```

Then trying to create the `getReviewTemplate` from `theme/checkout/onepage.phtml` as below

```
$block=$this->getLayout()->createBlock('onestepcheckout_review')->getReviewTemplate();
                echo '<pre>'; print_r($block);
```

It throws the error as below

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getReviewTemplate() on a non-object

What is the wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You block type is wrong should be

```
createBlock('onestepcheckout_review')
```

**should be**

```
createBlock('onestepcheckout/review')
```

It logic like :

Block_TYpePrefix/RestOfClassname.

`onestepcheckout`  **block type prefix / group name** of module `Ucs_OneStepCheckout` Module as you define at `config.xml`

`<blocks>
        <onestepcheckout><!-- this is called as block type prefix / group name of module Ucs_OneStepCheckout -->
            <class>Ucs_OneStepCheckout_Block</class>
        </onestepcheckout>
....`

If you want to call `Ucs_OneStepCheckout_Block_Review` class as block type then convert like this:

- `Ucs_OneStepCheckout_Block` = `onestepcheckout`

`Review` = `review`

Between Block groupName & rest of class name a `/` should  come.

So block type is `onestepcheckout/review`

Comment: Can you look into this if possible please http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82142/loading-review-template-file-inside-the-block-and-rendering-it-to-other-template

Answer (score 1):

It's `onestepcheckout/review`, not `onestepcheckout_review` (class group alias, slash, snake cased rest of the class name)

Comment: can you look into this please http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82142/loading-review-template-file-inside-the-block-and-rendering-it-to-other-template